# How to condense a multiple group css query

Tags: css, selector

Is there a better way to write CSS subgroups? Right now I have this CSS:

```
.foo > really-long-set-of-similar-info > .bar:hover,
.foo > really-long-set-of-similar-info > .bar:focus,
.foo > really-long-set-of-similar-info > .bar.class{
    width: 2px;
}
```

Would be totally awesome if I could save space by doing something like this:

```
.foo > really-long-set-of-similar-info > .bar(:hover,:focus,.class){
    width: 2px;
}
```

Is it possible to do? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that .class is a modifier that should affect multiple instances of an interactive element (button, input), then kind of, sort of..

Using CSS custom properties you can set an initial value for the really-long-set-of-similar-info, the just redefine the variable for the modifier.

```
really-long-set-of-similar-info{width: var(--width)}
(...)
.class{--width:2px}
```

https://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/RxVgrv
I've previously made that pen showcasing that awesome feature of CSS variables.

Problem is browser compatibility with IE (as always), so a fallback to graceful degradation will be required, if that's a valid choice for the particular effect you want to use.

Other than that, a simple pre-procesor mixin that takes the base selector and the properties as parameters and pukes out the three comma separated long selectors is a totally valid option.

Something the likes of

```
@mixin width($selector, $width) {
  #{$selector}.class,
  #{$selector}:focus,
  #{$selector}:hover {
    width: $width;
  }
}

@include width(button, 400px);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sfgs60or/1/

That could easily be modified to take an array of key-values in order to affect multiple properties

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using sass right now, but I checked the output and some of those end queries were like a mile long. So I am optimizing it right now. Interesting post on css variables. I have never used those before, so it is something to check out for sure.

Comment: well, no way to collapse the three status in a simpler declaration of compiled CSS. Maybe what you should think of is getting rid of the long chain. If that's a placeholder for a lot of selectors, then you're most likely over-qualifying your selectors.

Comment: That's possible, yeah. It's a navigation bar with many themes though. So in order to get my css 3 levels deep I need the nesting. Thanks for the good effort man. This is not possible without preprocessors it seems. :)